# PHP inside inline style

Tags: php, html, laravel

I want to use a variable inside my progress bar, so it changes depending on the status of each $projek, but I couldn't get it to work by simply putting it in the style
here is my code

```
@foreach($projek as $projek)
    <div style="padding-bottom: 16px;">
        <h6 style="font-weight: 600;">{{$projek->name}}</h6>
        <!-- <h7>{{$user->where('id',$projek->user_id)->pluck('name')}}</h7> -->
        <h6>{{$projek->status}}</h6>
        <div class="progress" style="height:8px">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: '{{$projek->status}}' %"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Here is the output
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXcux.png)

Comment: It seems `$projek->status` already contains the `%` sign, so you don't need to write it in the CSS style. Just use an inspector to see what CSS property you are applying, learn how to debug easy code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your code. Instead

```
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: '{{$projek->status}}' %"></div>
```

you should use

```
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: {{$projek->status}}% "></div>
```

While rendering, maybe your '%' was being ignored.

Comment: Would u check this out please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68526658/session-still-submitted-after-redirecting-view

Comment: Done, I have posted answer for that question too :)